# View controller inside tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Hello I have tab bar controller with 5 elements. When I press the last one there are bunch of buttons which needs to show another view controller and then when I press second time to that tab bar button it needs to be revert its first condition (bunch of buttons) it is like a navigator. I tried to use following code:

```
let destinationVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "third") as? ThirdVC
self.tabBarController?.present(destinationVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

However, view controller appears in a new screen and my tab bar controller is gone. How can I open my view controller above tab bar controller? Is it possible to do it ?

Comment: try `self.tabBarController?.navigationController?.present(destinationVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: Nope it didn't work for me do I need to add a navigation controller inside of my tab bar?

Comment: either you can simply change the current vc for the tabBarcontroller  `tabBarController.addChildViewController(vc)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try getting reference of the tabbar viewcontroller :

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarcontroller") as! UITabBarController
viewcontroller.selectedIndex = indexofyourvc i.e 0,1 etc
```

And push with the navigation controller :

```
self.navController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true )
```

Comment: Shall I add navigation controller from storyboard that tab bar controller because it is not doing anything right now?

Comment: Yes, add the navigation controller from storyboard or you can take reference of root view controller as
let navController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController .    If it fits your project

Comment: I have added and it works with some changes I could not understand why you add that selected index thing because the page that I need to navigate is another view controller. I change your code         
`let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "third") as! ThirdVC
        //viewController.selectedIndex = 4
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true) `